# Absolute <ul> for dropdown shows at wrong place on IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, position, css-position

If you try that in FireFox:
http://jsfiddle.net/rJUKT/2/

it works fine. The dropdown menu shows at the bottom of its parent like that:
[image: Dropmenu working fine]

But if you try it with IE7, the dropdown menu shows at the right, like that:
[image: Bug in IE7]

Any idea why it does that?

**HTML**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
    <ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <span>Menu 1</span>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="">Link 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 1.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 1.4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span>Menu 2</span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2.4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu { width: 100%; float: right; list-style: none; margin-top: 5px; color: #2A4153; }
#menu li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #e1f1ff;
    border:  1px solid #93b5d4;
    margin: 0 1px 0 1px;
    padding: 4px 0 0 0;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 20px;
}

#menu li a, #menu li span { padding: 4px 7px 2px 7px; cursor: pointer;  }

#menu li ul {
    clear: both;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    width: 150px;
    margin: -1px 0 0 -2px;
}

#menu li ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    border:  1px solid #93b5d4;
    border-top: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-image: url('16x16/eye.png');
    background-position: 4px 4px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
}
#menu li ul li a, #menu li ul li span { display:block; padding-left: 25px; }
#menu li ul li:hover { background-color: #e5f6e8; border:  1px solid #93d4a2; border-top: none; }

#menu li:hover { background-color: #e5f6e8; border: 1px solid #93d4a2; border-bottom: none; }
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    $('#menu li').hover(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $('ul', this).slideDown(100);

        },
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('ul', this).slideUp(100);        
        }
    );


});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it out this. Some css properties updated in this

http://jsfiddle.net/vkVHC/

Answer (score 4):

You need to set "top" and "left" properties for dropdown UL

Comment: +1 Exactly.  By default, they're inheriting the properties set (top and left) for the parent ul.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this ! Works like a charm ! (tested on IE / FF)

Answer (score 1):

If that's the only reason you're using jQuery (for the dropdown effect on hover), you may as well do it using CSS instead (and thus save many kBs being loaded by the site).  Also, Alexei's answer is correct.